# Override after pseudo element on matching element+element css

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Trying to achieve a simple effect in a chat app, where if a user messages, after his username should always appear a `:` but if a bot messages, his message will have a class of .bot and i would like to override that `user:after` to have different after content.

I can't modify the html since its dynamically generated.

```css
.user {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
.user:after {
  content: ": ";
}
.user:after + .bot {
  content: "=> ";
}
```

```html
<span class="user">User1</span>
<span class="message">Hello</span>
<br />
<span class="user">Bot</span>
<span class="bot">Hello</span>
```

Ideally the output should be:
[image: output]

But the css is fine for me to edit

Is this possible at all? Or should i pursue a different approach.

Comment: now that you modified your question, you are asking for something that is already doing it, so what's the point of the question?

Comment: sorry, was just editing it incorrectly

Comment: It's really unclear as to what the ideal result should look like.

Comment: @Paulie_D totally, OP is explaining by comments while editing the question , making it hard to give a properly answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that the current updated question already does what OP is trying to achieve

---

You can use `::before` pseudo element

Just FYI, you can style the pseudo elements (as I did)

```css
.user {
  background: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
.message::before,
.bot::before {
  background: red;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  left: -4px
}
.message::before {
  content: ":";
}
.bot::before {
  content: "=>";
}
```

```html
<span class="user">User1</span>
<span class="message">Hello</span>
<br />
<span class="user">Bot</span>
<span class="bot">Hello</span>
```

Comment: Now this is a good solution, but... the user classes will have quite different styling from the message classes. Assigning the content before would prevent the same style from user to be on the `:` or `=>`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, but ive edited mine, the idea was, the arrow or `:` should sit within the user.

Comment: explain: *the arrow or : should sit within the user* , you mean having both at the same position independent of the username you will have?

Comment: Should share the user style, thats why :after is important... before does not help me

Answer (score 0):

As per your updated question, here is the code snippet for you:

```css
.user + span:before{
    content: ": ";
    /*other rules you assign*/
}

.user + .bot:before { /*overriding just for bot*/
    content: "=> ";
}
```

```html
<span class="user">User1</span>
<span class="message">Hello</span>
<br />
<span class="user">Bot</span>
<span class="bot">Hello</span>
```

Otherwise you can't override as CSS has no parent element selector.

Comment: Sorry, cant assign it, since its dynamically generated.

Comment: Sorry, still this does not work as intended. Check here http://codepen.io/knuxus/pen/zBwWBr?editors=1100

Comment: See the original question, with the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.user:after {
  content: ": ";
}
.user + .bot:after {
  content: "=> ";
}
```

Comment: and how .user:after will go for .bot? This will not solve the OP problem.

Answer (score -2):

Currently there is no css-only way of solving this.